# Typo resistant pin codes

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, generation

### Background

I was working on a system where for convenience (not security) people could use four digit codes to identify themselves. I figured this is something that may actually be useful in many real cases, yet is well enough defined that it could make a nice challenge!

### Explanation of pin codes and typo resistant sets

EDIT: Based on the comments, this is probably a more formal definition:

> I think a mathematical way of specifying what you are looking for is a
> maximal set of strings with length 4 over the alphabet
> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} with minimum pairwise hamming distance 2, if it
> helps others.

There are 10000 possible pin codes (0000-9999).

Example pin code

```
1234
```

However, since a typo is easily made you are to generate a set of pincodes that is resistant to a single typo.

Example of set that is NOT resistant to single typo:

```
0000
0005 (if you mistype the last digit as 0 instead of 5, you get another code in the set)
```

Example of set that IS resistant to single typo

```
0000
0011
0101
0202
```

### Allowed outputs

The allowed output can be a bit flexible, specifically:

- A pincode may be a string or a number
- You may always have separators (e.g. comma, newline), however if your codes are always represented as 4 digits separators are optional
- The codes should be represented by 0-9, not other characters

Example sets:

```
0011,0022: OK
00220011: OK
11,22,33: OK
112233: NOT OK
abcd,abef: NOT OK
{'1111',/n'2222'}: OK
```

### Scoring system

The primary score is the number of unique pin codes generated (note that 0001,1000 would count as 2).

Edit:
If your code does not always generate the same amount of unique pin codes you must estimate the amount it will at least generate in 95% of the cases and you may use that as your score. So for example if you uniformly randomly generate between 300 and 400 unique pincodes, your score would be 395.

In case there is a tie, the shortest code wins!

Please post your score as: Language, #Unique codes generated with bytes (e.g. Python, 30 codes generated with 123 bytes)

(I guess formally this could be rewritten to 'generate X typo resistant pin codes' but as I have no idea what X is I will keep it like this, this also allows simpler solutions to compete against each other on lenght for 'third place' and beyond.)

---

In principle no inputs are needed and for simplicity sake I will not make it part of the challenge and scoring, but it would be interesting to see how the code would need to be changed to allow for various length pin codes.

Comment: Please define precisely what a "typo" is. Why is 0005 -> 0000 not allowed, but 0011 -> 0000 is?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the answer "print all codes between 0000 and 9999" work?

Comment: I think a mathematical way of specifying what you are looking for is a maximal set of strings with length 4 over the alphabet `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` with minimum pairwise hamming distance 2, if it helps others.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound

Comment: Must the output be deterministic? A simple greedy algorithm finds 712, but a random algorithm (for the same byte count in my language of choice) often finds 750 and sometimes as many as 765.

Comment: @pxeger I think my counter example already shows that printing all codes does not work. I have included the description of Sisiphus to formalize the set requirements.

Comment: @Neil It does not have to be deterministic, but I do want the algorithm to 'almost always' give the number you use as score. I will add in some wording stating that the score you achieve 95% of the time may be presented, if that is not clear enough feel free to propose a refinement.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Ah I understand now. It wasn't at all clear to me that the aim was to find pin codes where making a typo **couldn't** accidentally produce another valid code. I thought the aim was to allow the code whether or not a typo was made.

Comment: _If your code does not always generate the same amount of unique pin codes you must estimate the amount it will at least generate in 95% of the cases_ -> This can't be easily verified. I think the output should be deterministic. It would not prevent from using a random search with a well chosen seed.

Comment: A proof 1000 is optimal: drop the last digit from all PINs. All the resultant PINs must be unique (otherwise there's a pair with distance 1). There are 1000 unique PINs with length 3.

Comment: So tempting to ask the same question but with the Levenshtein distance instead!

Comment: @graffe If you are considering it, consider Damerau-Leveshtein instead.

Comment: @graffe wouldn't that be the same result, given the fixed output length and that we only allow one change (i.e. removals and additions can't happen)?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann That's why Wheat Wizard suggested including transpositions as well.

Comment: Not sure if this should have been closed for unclarity while it is getting great answers that all solve the same problem. Either way, thanks to everyone who made an attempt I upvoted all answers and accepted the shortest one! (Though in practice I foresee people might use the python one more often ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `M`, 6 bytes, 1000 codes

```
k2'∑₀Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJNIiwiIiwiazIn4oiR4oKA4biKIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Uses that the digit sum must be divisible by 10.

```
k2'∑₀Ḋ
k2'    # Filter for elements in [0, 10000]:
   ∑₀Ḋ #  Is the digit sum divisible by 10?
```

Comment: I think you meant `[0, 10000]` in your explanation, instead of `[0, 1000]`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 1000 unique pin codes, 44 bytes

```python
i=0;exec'print i+int(`i`,11)%10;i+=10;'*1000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZvaAoM69EIVMbSGokZCboGBpqqhoaWGdq2wJJdS1DAwOD//8B)

I suspect 1000 pin codes is optimal. You can check the [verification program](https://tio.run/##Pdjdih3GEUXh6/RTHBuMZ0CE/u/qgHKVF5HRmAjLkpBksPPyylcK5GZjS0szZ3p1VVfNp7@@/vvjh/Ht29uXXx9v3335@vTm1eOX53@Uv31@@frH5w@PL3/8/vTn44fXj78ev378/Pjzlf949@Hxn3efnn78qc63Pz5@evgn///vX56fS3n/eP14n1/s9zefnt59@Prq8fHTy4en@vz3zy9v3r5/9@Hly9Nzgvkl3319@T2/5Hvf9M2XLy@fvz7evH//9Nvj9ev//R3m@yf77dX3/39@/PP1o3//NL99/3fP5dNn3@Tp5399/PDyw8/P377V0lrpvYxR5ixrlb3LOSWi3Ftabf66l9ZHaWOWNldpa5e2T2knSgvMraXXXnobvs4sfazS5y59ndJ3lH5u6YG5rYw6ymizjL58w13GPGWsKGPfMk4tIzC3l1lnmW2V2XeZ4/hkUea6Ze5a5mllBuaOsuoqq@2y@ilrRFnz@hFqWbuVdXpZgbmz7LrLbqfsHmWPW/asZa/mZ@1ln1F2YO4qp55yWpTTbzmjljNbOauXs4dDmeUE5u4SNUq0W6LXEqOVmL3EGiX2LHGW08PcU2695bZabm/ljl7uHOWuWe5e5Z5dbmCuc6x50DVPuuZR1zzrmodd87RrHnfN86554PWmNEfemjPnB9ycemuOvTXn3pqDb83JtxYJO/vWHX7rTr91x08puBPQOgOtU9A6B61Hwiy0QUMbPLRBRBtMuAXgwUUbZLTBRhuRMB9tEtImI21S0iYnbZLi4oAnLW3y0mYkzExb1LTFTVvktMVOW/S0xY@7Bl4MtRUJc9Q2SW2z1DZNbfPUNlFtM9U2Va4neEfCbLVDVzt8tUNYO4y1Q1k7nLVDWjusudEJ8@bQwMFcC@pacNeCvBbstaCvBX8tIuE0eCv4qqV2VVO76qldFdWummpXVbWrrtqNhNVWr1k0NaumZtnUrJuahVOzcmqWTs3aqVk8lcHuXggGO2dZcGDnKRjsflbBYPfJBYPdFxQM9s5g7wyqUXBn0B@B@8n6j4QZ7IPBPhjsg8E@GOyDQWUNHgz6IuARCTPYJ4N9Mtgng30y2CeDfTKoE4Ang75twgz2xWBfDPbFYF8M9sVgXwz2xaDmAV6RMIM@KHgz2DeDfTPYN4N9M9g3g30zqN8kzKCbDD4M9sNgPwz2w2A/DPbDYD8M9hMJM6hHgSO7YTDYg8EeDPZgsAeDPRjsEQmnwatqtTXwVbWOD3xVbb@qtl9V26@q7TcSVrWjZgOs2QFrtsCaPbBmE6zZBWu2wZp9sGYjrAwObUAwOJSoYFAHBSsGweBwtUUkzOBwfwSDg1vB4HDu2XTBTlEwOPyEgsHhGwsGhz8UDI7B4BgM6tP5OjDoLiTMoL8ETwbHZHBMBsdkcEwGx2RQawfPSJhBtwe8GByLwbEYHIvBsRgci8GxGPQaJMyg9gLeDPoA4M3g2AyOzeDYDI7N4NiRMINeEPBh0A0FHwbHYXAcBsdhcBwGx4mEGRzBoEcHHAy60@BgcASDIxgcweCISDgNXlU7rqr1ToGvqlUF4Ktqx1W146racSNhVTtrPmY1X7Oaz1nN96zmg1bzRav5pNV802o@apXBqesLBqeOLBicumU@iWC9TzDo/BNmcGoXgsGplAWDU2EKBr2iYCUgImEGGQO7NYLB6Q4IBic/gkEPL9hJCAaVNNi3EwxO/1gwOOfK2YHBORn0VifMoJ4PXgy6FeDF4FwMzsXgXAzOxeBckTCD3nfwZlDbAO@cSjaDczM4N4NzMzh3JMzgPAwaCcCHQY0GfBj0UcCHwXkYnCcSZnAGgzMYNEWAg0GtCRwM@vDgYHBGJJwGr6qdV9XOq2oNHuCrajUz8FW1flzwjYRV7ao5mNScTGqOJjVnk5rDSc3ppOZ4UnM@qTmgVAadEtiTLRhcnlPB4PI45owD9nCJSJhBZQTW6wWDS@cWDC5dVTBoLALrX4JBfRasSQgGl5IXDC7lKBhcSiUnqYQZ9BCD3UfBIHdg5gWDixXB4HJiOXxFTl9gP4hgUHGD1/fJksG1GFyLwbUiYQbXZtDABt4M6v7gzaD7Ad4Mrs3g2pEwg@swuA6DZjzwYdB7AT4MulHgw@A6kTCDKxhcweAKBo2F4GDQCwMOBt1BcETCafCq2nVV7bqqdl1Va5IEX1XrTQJfVevWJqxqXV1DZs0ps@aYWXPOrDlo1pw0a46aNWfNmsNmZVBvA5vQBIPbvCUY3GYhwaChFWzqEAx6/MCedsGg8wJ7dgWD25MoGDTnJsyg6QjsFREMKiiwfi0Y3HqpYHDrczkaR87GYO1HMKjjghW6yO1AEQoGtwIRDG43PcdpsFsoGNSjwXwLBjcXIhJmcDsiwaAJHOzDCAZ1dfBmkHfwjoQZ3IfBfRjch0FDO/gw6NkHHwY1BvCJhBn0T8HB4A4GdzBozgcHgwYFcDColSScBq@q9c3AV9Xuq2r3VbVWA/BVtUYL8I2EVa0Hx8JQc2OouTLU3BlqLg01t4aaa0PNvaHm4lAZNJGADeSCQZcYbFgWDB6DrGDQFpIwg0ZWsNlPMKjLgU1ZgsFjAhIMHtNJLi6RmwvY0CAY9AyCPc@CQScH9hCKSJjB433KZQfs7RAMejjBurRg0FmD9UPB4NHYBIP2I7AWIhj01IIVq2CQnYQZPCpCMHjc1lypwG6SYNDjDGZZRMIM8gl2MKLnVsqgLQzsCwoGPefgEwkzqODBwaA/AgeDJxi0uIGDQfMeOCLhNHhVrRYBvqrWFwFfVXuuqrXrga@qNSEmrGqNiZa/mttfzfWv5v5XcwGsuQHWXAFr7oA1l8DKoD0CbGMTDHp6wHYjwaBPC7aFiEiYQXsl2KgvGDSbgA3VgkHXGdxzSzeMCgbDVJmrKNjEJxg0zYDNVoJBBQA2xQgGwzgiGLS9gj38gkHzD9gTKxhUMgkz6AzBXiXBoIUXrP8LBk1MYL1ZRMIMKjKwdiYYDK0md2SwNiAYNGOBlahgUBcGqwPBYLijgkFrNdj9EQyayhJm0DMNdoCCQWbBfjjBoE0c7MuISDgNXlXrYQdfVav0wVfV@kvwVbWWd/CNhFWt5c4iX3OTr7nK19zlay7zNbf5mut8zX2@xvelP3LrB1vQBYMGRrBVWDCox4AtnSJ/02IhLNcumL8oANvTBINGTLCNSDCoK4HtHoJBnxtsJcjfLYCN64JBQynYYCwY1McSZtDFBpslBYPXnCcYtLWATVSCQQ9dwgzqfGBDiGDwGhDyNxhgj7dg0OAL9rAKBj2NYK@XYNBpgr0T@UsPsK4vGDQqJ8yg2Qms7QkGlRtYSxIMXu1CMGiXSphBwzVYvQgG9WOwuywYvO5Z/moF7A6INEiNULXmM7BjE6pWSYN9QKFqr38sVO1/AQ).

### How was this discovered?

The process for discovering this rather simple formula was quite messy for me. The first insight I had was that you can transform this into a graph problem - let the PIN numbers be nodes and connect edges if and only if the hamming distance between the PIN numbers is greater than 1. Then the problem boils down to finding a [maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) of the graph. From reading some papers apparently there was a simple C program [available in the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20020201175854/http://www.tcs.hut.fi:80/%7Epat/wclique.html) that solves the maximal clique problem for small instances, so I downloaded it (and patched it a little bit since it doesn't compile on a modern compiler). I wrote a simple driver program to generate input in the format it expected and ran it. It was too slow for the full problem but I noticed something odd about its output for smaller instances:

```python
...
level = 9997(10000) best = 100 time =     0.65
level = 9998(10000) best = 100 time =     0.65
level = 9999(10000) best = 100 time =     0.65
level = 10000(10000) best = 100 time =     0.65
Record: 9 10 21 32 43 54 65 76 87 98 100 111 122 133 144 155 166 177 188 199 201 212 220 234 245 253 267 278 289 296 302 313 324 330 341 356 368 379 385 397 403 414 425 431 447 458 469 470 486 492 504 515 526 537 548 559 560 571 582 593 605 616 623 638 649 657 661 672 680 694 706 717 728 739 740 751 762 773 784 795 807 818 829 835 846 852 863 874 881 890 908 919 927 936 942 950 964 975 983 991
```

For the first 1000 PINs, the optimal clique had 100 nodes, which suspiciously looks like just the number of PINs divided by 10. And also, every prefix from `000..099` appeared once. This led me to hypothesize that there was some closed form solution of the form:

```python
10 * i + f(i) % 10
```

It looks like `f` is almost just `f(i) = i` but occasionally it jumps some extra.

After toying around a little bit, I came across the formula `(i + i / 10 + i / 100) % 10`, which passes. But `(i + i / 10 + i / 100) % 10` is just `int(str(i), 11) % 10`, that is, reinterpreting the digits of `i` in base 11! This gives the final answer.

Comment: Nice solution! You probably noticed this already, but your numbers are those where the last digit equals the sum of the remaining digits mod 10. Another set are the numbers whose digits add to a multiple of 10 though those seem [longer to generate](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFPITNPoSgxLz1VwxIINK24FDLTgGIlGgl5CTqGhpqqhgY2hlYFRUAhhbz//wE "Python 2 – Try It Online"). It makes sense for both these sets why changing any digit must ruin the property. For base 2, both the corresponding sets are the [Evil Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_number).

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1000 codes generated with 7 bytes

```
9Ý4ãʒOθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8vBck8OLT03yP7fj/38A)

Works using the observation that you can append any function \$ f(a, b, c) \$ to all 3-digit PINs \$ abc \$ iff after fixing two of the variables you get a permutation - no value appears more than once. This code uses \$ f(a, b, c) = (1 - a - b - c) \mod 10 \$, which is equivalent to the statement that the last digit of the PIN's digit sum is 1.

```
9Ý     push [0, 1, 2, ..., 9]
4ã     push the fourth cartesian power, all choices of four values from the above list
ʒ      keep only elements for which the following returns 1
 O     sum all values
 θ     take the last digit of the sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 1000 codes, 16 bytes

```
(~10!+/')#+!4#10
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJzTqDM0UNTWV9dU1lY0UTY0AAAbWQL6)

-5 bytes thanks to @CommandMaster and @ovs!

Uses @xnor's clever observation that each pin can satisfy `(digit sum) mod 10 == 0`.

### Explanation

- `+!4#10` generate all 4-digit pins
- `(...)#` filter...

  - `~10!+/'` equivalent to `(digit sum) mod 10 == 0`

Comment: You can replace `1=` with `~` for -1

Comment: @CommandMaster unfortunately I think that would also allow sums ending in 2-9 to filter through.

Comment: Your *digit list* can be ``+10\``. And `~` is basically `0=`, so that should work as well. You might want to look into producing output as a 4-column matrix, this can be slightly shorter

Comment: @ovs ooh ok, now I see what CommandMaster meant. Thanks for the help!

Comment: there's "filter out" - the negation of filter: `(~`..`)#` -> `(`..`)_`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 1000 codes, 17 bytes

```
ＵＢ0←ＥΦＸχ⁴¬﹪Σιχ⮌Ｉι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYhBCsIwEADvviL0tIEIKXiyNwVPVkr7gpCuGoxd2W7q89OdwwxMfAeOFHKtE8olxM@LqSwzNL6x3WHgtAic7/gUZ/rwg1vKggwD/dWtd@ZknXmQQE9zyQRT@ULS1XprNSNuyCvCNayiX@lqrcct7w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses @xnor's observation.

```
ＵＢ0                 Zero-fill the output.
   ←Ｅ         ⮌Ｉι   Output right-aligned an in reverse order.
       χ            Predefined variable `10`
      Ｘ             Raised to power
        ⁴           Literal integer `4`
     Φ              Filter over implicit range
            ι       Current value
           Σ        Digital sum
          ﹪         Modulo
             χ      Predefined variable `10`
         ¬          Is zero
```

By replacing the `⁴` with an `Ｎ` the program will accept the number of digits in the PIN as an input.

Comment: [`ＥΦＸχ⁴¬﹪ΣιχＩι`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDLTOnJLVIIyC/HEgaGugomGjqKPjlAyXzU0pz8jWCS3M1MoFChgaamkDKObG4BMjX1LT@//@/blkOAA) seems to work just fine for 12 bytes - it's allowed to output numbers. Is there a reason you didn't do that?

Comment: @CommandMaster Sure, [`ＩΦＸχ⁴¬﹪Σιχ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zpyS1SCMgvxxIGhroKJho6ij45Zdo@OanlObkawSX5mpkAoUMDTRBwPr///@6ZTkA) outputs numbers, but I wanted to output PIN codes.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 1000 codes, 46 bytes

Returns a comma-separated string. Based on [xnor's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249759/typo-resistant-pin-codes#comment557406_249762).

```javascript
f=(n=1e3)=>--n&&n+[~(~(n/100)-n-n/10)%10,f(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xbsMwDEX3noINUIdEJNVuM7WQgQw5QUfDAy3LqQtHEiQ3Y67uSJ26PXy@/8EfvnEycQ6rdH602zZpdLqx76RbKV1VuUN3xzu616auSTpZgF6aWkzoqN@iTaBhQvp8Mt4lv1i1@AvmOCenfMqkUljmFfdiT@rKAXOjhaQCj18rxxWPAmoqupp8PLP5Ri7G6U8eCjI8axigqqBTSnGvoh1/jUUMAoyAmYoU4ABoQGezm3sqo9DCW2n9f213jtHHj52AjgUMPRFtDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 61 bytes

```
l=[0...9999]
l[[mod(floor(i/10^{[0...3]}).total,10)fori=l]=0]
```

Outputs a list of numbers. Uses xnor's observation that the digit sum has to be a multiple of 10.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ch3ptnbx9i)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0o0djef0ls)